# What is this magento extesion?

Tags: magento

I want to calculate delivery cost and time. I found same one on the website. But i don't know what is the extension's name. Please tell me know, thanks.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turn on block and template path hints in magento´s configuration. Then you will recognize with what block class you are dealing and you can derive the actual module.

Comment: Sr, module of another website (I find it on internet)

Comment: ah i see... check the markup and see if you find anything that helps. There is no other chance from my point of view...if its custom developed you will never find the module... we have dozens of custom modules, which you might never find anywhere...